# after_destroy callback error "cannot update on new record object"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `after_destroy` callback like so:

```
after_destroy :update_max_depth_on_entire_tree
```

The definition is:

```
  def update_max_depth_on_entire_tree
    root = self.root
    root.check_or_update_max_tree_depth
    root.descendants.each { |c| 
      c.check_or_update_max_tree_depth
    }
  end

  def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
    update_columns(max_tree_depth: last_depth)      
  end

  def last_depth
    if child_ids.empty?
      return depth
    else
      return children.map{|c| c.last_depth}.max
    end
  end
```

Whenever I try to delete an object, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError at /posts/detecting-ramsay-is-offered-ceo-job
cannot update on a new record object
```

This is what the Server log looks like:

```
Started DELETE "/posts/detecting-ramsay-is-offered-ceo-job" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-05 09:56:24 -0500
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2xRY+A=", "id"=>"detecting-ramsay-is-offered-ceo-job"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (2.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 3]]
   (2.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'editor') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 3]]
  Post Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."slug" = 'detecting-ramsay-is-offered-ceo-job'  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Post Load (5.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (("posts"."ancestry" ILIKE '69/%' OR "posts"."ancestry" = '69'))
  Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE "roles"."resource_id" = $1 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $2  [["resource_id", 69], ["resource_type", "Post"]]
  FriendlyId::Slug Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "friendly_id_slugs".* FROM "friendly_id_slugs"  WHERE "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = $1 AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "friendly_id_slugs".id DESC  [["sluggable_id", 69], ["sluggable_type", "Post"]]
  SQL (1.5ms)  DELETE FROM "friendly_id_slugs" WHERE "friendly_id_slugs"."id" = $1  [["id", 47]]
  SQL (1.2ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 69]]
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."ancestry" = '69'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 281ms

ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError - cannot update on a new record object:
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:272:in `update_columns'
   () /app/models/post.rb:122:in `check_or_update_max_tree_depth'
   () /app/models/post.rb:130:in `update_max_depth_on_entire_tree'
```

How do I call this method, or achieve what I want to achieve (i.e. update an attribute on all the nodes on the tree, when 1 node has been deleted) without getting this error?

**Edit 1**

This is what my routes look like:

```
mark_as_published_post_path PUT /posts/:id/mark_as_published(.:format)  posts#mark_as_published
mark_as_unpublished_post_path   PUT /posts/:id/mark_as_unpublished(.:format)    posts#mark_as_unpublished
posts_path  GET /posts(.:format)    posts#index
POST    /posts(.:format)    posts#create
new_post_path   GET /posts/new(.:format)    posts#new
edit_post_path  GET /posts/:id/edit(.:format)   posts#edit
post_path   GET /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#show
PATCH   /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
PUT /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#destroy
status_path GET /:status(.:format)  posts#status {:status=>/confirmed|unconfirmed|corroborated/}
GET /posts/:id(.:format)    redirect(301, /%{id})
GET /:friendly_id(.:format) posts#show
GET /posts/:friendly_id(.:format)   posts#show
GET /rbt/:name(.:format)    redirect(301)
GET /:name(.:format)    posts#show
root_path   GET /   posts#index
```

And this is what my `PostController#Destroy` looks like:

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Report was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**Edit 2**

I believe the issue is with this portion of code:

```
  def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
    update_columns(max_tree_depth: last_depth)      
  end
```

What the error seems to be saying is that somewhere along the chain it encounters a new record, and it can't execute `update_columns(max_tree_depth: last_depth)` on an object that is a new record.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `before destroy`? Since you still use the object

Comment: So what I am trying to do is, I have a tree and I want to store the maximum depth of the tree in every node. If a node from within the tree, representing 1 level of depth, gets deleted, then the entire tree needs to be updated. i.e. if there are 6 levels and 1 level gets deleted, all other nodes on the tree need to know that the `max_tree_depth` is now 5 and not 6. I couldn't achieve that with a `before_destroy` because the node (and level) still exists.

Comment: I assume the error is generated since the object is already gone. So my suggestion would be to use before destroy and count - 1, because the object will soon be deleted... Only as a comment as I'm sure there are better and cleaner solutions...

Comment: That's the thing, it isn't gone. The delete action doesn't complete - you can tell by the `(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK` in the logs.

Comment: Ah ok, then I misunderstood

Comment: could you post your routes? and also output the log of the `root` object

Comment: Think you can check if `root` is in database before call `root.check_or_update_max_tree_depth` like `Root.where(id: root.id).present?`

Comment: You know what is happening, `root.descendants` is returning a blank collection - I think that could be it.

Comment: Nope `root.descendants` being empty is not the issue. I updated the question with another edit that spells out my most recent analysis of what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out by doing a few things. Wrapping my `update_column(max_tree_depth: last_depth)` inside a `new_record?` check like so:

```
  def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
    if new_record?
      return
    else
      update_column(:max_tree_depth, last_depth)
    end
  end
```

That got around that error.

And another error I was having was that whenever my callback encountered a record that was the root record, because of the fact that I am using the `:adopt` orphan strategy in ancestry to determine what to do with deleted posts, it was creating a new record from the `post.children` and assigning them root and throwing everything into wack.

So I just modified my code like so:

```
  def update_max_depth_on_entire_tree
    if max_tree_depth <= 0
      return
    else
      root = self.root
      root.check_or_update_max_tree_depth
      root.descendants.each { |c|
        c.check_or_update_max_tree_depth
      }
    end
  end
```

And that seems to have done it.

Answer (score 0):

This question has become a bit large to grasp, but I'll give it a shot. . .

Your latest update suggests that your problem lies in the fact that `update_columns` doesn't work on new records.  Why not use update_attributes` instead?

Change:

```
def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
  update_columns(max_tree_depth: last_depth)      
end
```

to:

```
def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
  update_attributes(max_tree_depth: last_depth)      
end
```

I found a discussion related to the issue of `update_columns` not working on new records from back in 2012 that may contain some information that could help you restructure parts of your app that are giving you trouble: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7226

**Update:**

You already answered this, but just noting here for completionist's sake. . .

An alternative solution is to simply add a conditional to your `update_columns` method that checks if the object is a `new_record?` or not:

```
if new_record?
  return
else
  update_column(:max_tree_depth, last_depth)
end
```

Comment: This is so close, but the problem is that `update_attributes` executes the callback (particularly the `after_save`) which sends it into an infinite loop. That's why I have to use something that updates the attribute, but doesn't execute the callbacks associated with the model.

Comment: Hmm, as I thought I will need to try to get a better grasp of the largeish subject matter of the question.  I'll try to do so within the next day.  Hopefully someone beats me to it, but I'll try to get back here if I'm needed.

Comment: I think I got it. I am going to post my answer. Thanks for trying though.